# Flex Builder: Can't find ManagedQuery or ManagedOperation

Tags: apache-flex, service, builder

This is the response to my question/error I get, but I don't know how to implement it, is there someone who can help me out with this one?

It turns out that my issues were caused by having two instances of the same data service class in two different components that were used in the same page. If I changed the components to share the same instance of the data service, then everything works just fine.

how to define a service in the main application or elsewhere which can be shared between components?

**Component A:**

```
<s:CallResponder id="getTblsupplierByIDResult"
    result="getTblsupplierByIDResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
<tblsupplierservice:TblsupplierService 
    id="tblsupplierService"     
    fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
    showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

**Component B:**

```
<s:CallResponder id="getAllTblsupplierByUserResult"/>
<tblsupplierservice:TblsupplierService
    id="tblsupplierService"
    fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
        showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

Wim

Comment: edited.  Can you please show the code for your service?  There shouldn't be a problem having more than one instance of a service in 2 different component (other than architecturally) unless you have some funky code within it or something that's manipulating the instances.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this to work I believe is to include an xmlns declaration, service declaration and callresponder declaration in the main root Application so that this is the firsat instance created and all sub components relate to this first instance.

If it works let me know, as I have many problems with this sort of Managed Data thing.